# dplyr to replace all variable which matches specific string

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, null, sparklyr

Is there an equivalent `dplyr` which does this? I'm after 'replace all' which matches string xxx with NA

```
is.na(df) <- df=="xxx"
```

I want to execute a `sparklyr` command using the pipe function from R to Spark dataframe

```
tbl(sc,"df") %>%
```

and sticking the first script above doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want to replace NA values with a specified string? Or the other way around? Your first statement is confusing to me.

Comment: Replace all variables with string "xxx" to NA. First script is to assign NA to all variables in df which matches "xxx"

Answer (score 0):

Replace "XXX" with the string you want to look for:

```
#Using dplyr piping
library(dplyr)
df[] = df %>% lapply(., function(x) ifelse(grepl("XXX", x), NA, x))

#Using only the base package
df[] = lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(grepl("XXX", x), NA, x))
```

This method assesses each column in your data frame one-by-one and applies the function to lookup "XXX" and replace it with NA.

Comment: Running the pipe followed by collect (from Spark to local R dataframe) gave me an error "Error in UseMethod("collect") : no applicable method for 'collect' applied to an object of class "list". So improvised as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(.,function(x)ifelse(grepl("xxx",x)==T,NA,x))), stringsAsFactors=FALSE), and none of the "xxx" was converted to NA