# SparkR groupBy multiple column with applying filter on each

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I have a dataset which has more than 500 million records. I want to apply a `group by` clause on multiple columns to get the count. While grouping I also need to make sure that the result count is only for the specific value in the column.

I have Loan Table which has
customer_id,loan_id, installment_amt, installment_status
Installment_status contains multiple values 'B', 'N', 'C'

In a single query, I want to know for each customer_id, loan_id, what is the total number of installments, No of installments Having 'B' only and No Of installments having 'C'.

I am new to SparkR trying to do something like below-

```
RESULT <- summarize(
  groupBy(LOAN, "customer_id", "loan_id"),
  NO_OF_Installment=count(LOAN$installment_amt),
  BILLED_INSTALLMENTS=count(LOAN$$installment_status=='B'),
  CCANCELLED_INSTALLMENT=count(LOAN$$installment_status=='C')
)
```

It is giving me same count for billed_installment as well as cancelled_installment.

I am not quite sure that filtering while counting will work. I don't see anything in [the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/groupBy.html). But I have seen this code working in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find `SparkR` code to be a bit easier to read with pipes since it looks more similar to Python or Scala versions of the same, so I'll use `magrittr`.

```
library(magrittr)
```

The basic idea is to use the `ifelse` method.

In SparkQL:

```
LOAN %>% createOrReplaceTempView('LOAN')
sql("
select customer_id, loan_id, count(installment_amt) as no_of_installment,
       count(if(installment_status = 'B', 1, NULL)) as billed_installments,
       count(if(installment_status = 'C', 1, NULL)) as cancelled_installments
from loan
group by customer_id, loan_id
") %>% summarize
```

In "native" `SparkR` it should be:

```
LOAN %>% groupBy('customer_id', 'loan_id') %>%
  summarize(
    NO_OF_Installment = count(.$installment_amt),
    BILLED_INSTALLMENTS = count(ifelse(.$installment_status == 'B', 1, NA)),
    CANCELLED_INSTALLMENTS = count(ifelse(.$installment_status == 'C', 1, NA))
  )
```

I'm not 100% sure whether you need `NA` or `NULL` as the `no` value in `ifelse`, but I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45095008/3576984) answer using `NA`.

---

As to why your own approach is not working, I think your approach would work for *`sum`* instead of *`count`*.

`count` counts up the number of non-`NULL` rows in a column. `LOAN$installment_status=='C'` is a `boolean` column, so it will only be `NULL` if `LOAN$installment_status` is `NULL`. `count` doesn't care about the *actual value* of the column -- it doesn't even care about the *data type*.

The closest `base` R equivalent to `count` is `length`. `length(numeric(100))` is the same as `length(logical(100))`.

Instead, you might be more comfortable thinking of this as a `sum` -- the `base` R equivalent is like `sum(installment_status == 'B')`. In `SparkR`, this would look like

```
sum(as.integer(.$installment_status == 'B'))
# or
sum(ifelse(.$installment_status == 'B', 1, 0))
```

Unfortunately while `base` R implicitly converts `logical` type into `integer` when we `sum`, `SparkR` requires explicit conversions, hence these two alternatives that make the conversion from `boolean` to `integer` explicit.

Comment: Thank you!. Your answer helped me to think little different. Instead of count(if(installment_status = 'B', 1, NULL)) I thought to use sum(if(installment_status = 'B', 1, 0)). With this, I don't have to worry about null values